# No delete the last file on dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am using the [Dropzone JS plugin](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload and manage images on my server. Everything works great, but now I need to force the user to keep at least one image for the product. That means that if the users wants to change the images they need to upload a new one image before they delete the old one.

I can manage it on the server side, but I can't figure out a way to retain the thumbnail visible and notify the user they are not allowed to delete the last one. Just keeping the image on the server without telling the users whats going on will result on a bad UX.

**Here is my code**

```
$("div#myId").dropzone({
    url: "/stores/sell_upload/",
    maxFiles: 4,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    renameFile: function(file) {
        let newName = file.name.replace("." + file.name.split(".").pop(), "") + "-" + new Date().getTime() + "." + file.name.split(".").pop();
        return newName;
    },
    removedfile: function(file) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/stores/sell_upload/",
            data: {
                name: file.name,
                action: "delete"
            }
        });
        var _ref;
        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, Wouldn't it be easier if you validated the files in the action of the button to save? I mean, the dropzone area can be empty but you in your button action validate that it has to be at least one file in the area to be saved.